# Comma needed using and em-dash paranthetical within a list?

Tags: grammar, commas, lists, em-dashes

What's the correct use of an em-dash within a comma-separated list?

E.g. is, "Tom only likes four colours: red, blue—although he's on the fence—, green, and yellow" correct or is, "Tom only likes four colours: red, blue—although he's on the fence— green, and yellow"? Neither looks correct to me...

Comment: No matter how you punctuate this, it's confusing.  I would rephrase it entirely.

Comment: I'd go with Tom only likes four colours: red, blue—although he's on the fence, green, and yellow. The em dash is not forced to pair up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dashes to provide parenthetical information to an item in list - example from BBC?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562466/dashes-to-provide-parenthetical-information-to-an-item-in-list-example-from-bb)

Comment: I hadn't found that specific post before writing this, @k1eran That definitely provides more clarity, thank you! With that in mind, I think phoog is correct; I've decided to re-jig the whole thing. Thank you!